# web-fonts are delivered only if logged-in

Tags: wordpress, caching, webfonts

I observe something I don't understand:
On my wordpress-blog, I use a bunch of self-hosted web-fonts, addressed like this:

`@font-face {
  font-family: 'Myfont-Light';
  src: url('/wp-content/webfonts/panton/2DD364_1A_0.eot');
  src: url('/wp-content/webfonts/panton/2DD364_1A_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('/wp-content/webfonts/panton/2DD364_1A_0.woff2') format('woff2'),url('/wp-content/webfonts/panton/2DD364_1A_0.woff') format('woff'),url('/wp-content/webfonts/panton/2DD364_1A_0.ttf') format('truetype');
}`

the website is http://davidbraun.ch […]

These fonts are only served if the browser is logged in (accessing the site in different browsers show the page with default system-fonts until I log in)

Since I am not tech-savvy, I would like to understand what's going on here... Does anyone know this issue, and how I could resolve it?

Many thanks!
david

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your using a caching plugin that is set to not to cache for known-users (logged in users).

Check your plugin settings, clear and purge any caches and check your .htaccess, you may need to potentially update your mod_rewrite_rules.

W3 Cache is a great caching plugin if you don't already have something setup, or are experiencing difficulties with your existing plugin.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do I get it right – the web fonts aren't delivered because the pages come from the cache, but will come through when the page is accessed when the cache is bypassed?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm assuming anyway from how you have described your issue. You can use Firebug for Firefox or Web Inspector in Safari or Chrome to see all the resources being served to the browser, your font's show as 304 not modified which indicates they are being cached, whats controlling the cache however is unclear. Do you use Cloudflare, or a plugin that controls the cache?